move the grid in the direction of the mouse pointe in godot
I'm creating a farming game in godot 4. I want to write an event that when I select a hoe in the selected bar, a grid will appear under the character's feet and the mouse pointer, but I can't do it.
I hope you can help me, thanks.
Here is my code:
extends Node2D
@onready var tile_map = $TileMap
@onready var player =  $Players/player
var tile_pos_infront_of_player 

func _ready():
    player.global_position = Global.player_pos

    DisplayServer.cursor_set_custom_image(load("res://tilemap/pointer_c.png"), 0, Vector2i(0, 0))   
func _physics_process(delta):
    update_gridhelper_visibility()

    match Global.selected:
      0:
        if player:
           var player_pos = player.global_position 

           var tile_pos_player_is_on : Vector2 = tile_map.local_to_map(player_pos)
           tile_pos_infront_of_player= tile_pos_player_is_on + player.face_direction

           var mouse_pos : Vector2 = get_global_mouse_position()

           var direction_to_mouse = (mouse_pos - player_pos).normalized()
           var gridhelper_pos = tile_pos_infront_of_player + direction_to_mouse
           $gridhelper.global_position = gridhelper_pos  * 16
 func update_gridhelper_visibility():
    if Global.selected == 0:
       $gridhelper.show()
    else:
       $gridhelper.hide()

I hope everyone will help me complete it quickly, thank you
